# NEO4J Cypher Query: Optionally find connections within search result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**Sample Graph:**

[image]

*Sample Graph Creation Query: At the end of this question.*

Now I am searching where 'Alpha' and 'Charlie' work, so I write:

```
MATCH p=((a:Cust)-[r]-(b:Comp))
WHERE a.title = "Delta" OR a.title="Charlie"
RETURN a.title, extract(i IN relationships(p)| type(i)) as relation, b.title
```

[image: I get the proper result]

This works great, but additionally I want to find out whether Alpha and Charlie are directly connected with one another. something like what NEO4J does in its graph representation. like 
[image: like this]

---

**What I tried,**

```
MATCH p=((a:Cust)-[r]-(b:Comp))
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=((a)--(:Cust))
WHERE a.title = "Delta" OR a.title="Charlie" AND p2 is not null
RETURN a.title, extract(i IN relationships(p)| type(i)) as relation, b.title, extract(x IN nodes(p2) | x.title)
```

but the result is not satisfactory, I want it limited to a--a but since a--a was blank I tried a--:Cust
[image]

---

**Sample Graph Creation Query:**

```
CREATE (a:Cust {title: "Alpha"})
CREATE (b:Cust {title: "Bravo"})
CREATE (c:Cust {title: "Charlie"})
CREATE (d:Cust {title: "Delta"})

create (g:Comp {title: "Google"})
create (f:Comp {title: "Facebook"})
create (s:Comp {ttile: "Stackoverflow"})

MATCH (a:Cust {title: "Alpha"}), (b:Cust {title: "Bravo"})
CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)

MATCH (a:Cust {title: "Alpha"}), (c:Cust {title: "Charlie"})
CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(c)

MATCH (d:Cust {title: "Delta"}), (c:Cust {title: "Charlie"})
CREATE (d)-[:KNOWS]->(c)

MATCH (c:Cust {title: "Charlie"}), (b:Cust {title: "Bravo"})
CREATE (c)-[:KNOWS]->(b)


MATCH (g:Comp {title: "Google"}), (s:Comp {title: "Stackoverflow"})
CREATE (g)-[:USES]->(s)

MATCH (f:Comp {title: "Facebook"}), (s:Comp {ttile: "Stackoverflow"})
CREATE (f)-[:USES]->(s)

MATCH (d:Cust {title: "Delta"}), (s:Comp {ttile: "Stackoverflow"})
CREATE (d)-[:WORKS_AT]->(s)

MATCH (d:Cust {title: "Delta"}), (g:Comp {title: "Google"})
CREATE (d)-[:WORKS_AT]->(g)

MATCH (a:Cust {title: "Alpha"}), (f:Comp {title: "Facebook"})
CREATE (a)-[:WORKS_AT]->(f)

MATCH (c:Cust {title: "Charlie"}), (s:Comp {ttile: "Stackoverflow"})
CREATE (c)-[:WORKS_AT]->(s)
```

Comment: It seems to me that you have an error in the property name for the `stackoverfow` node - `ttitle` - extra `t`?

Comment: I resolved that after making the query, so now i have both title and ttile for stackoverflow... ill fix the create statements and hence in my snapshots stackoverflow is being printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting question: how easy is it to know that the nodes from different paths obtained by the pattern have a relationship with each other. As an example, you can make this query:

```
WITH  ["Delta", "Charlie"] as custNames 
MATCH p = (a:Cust)-[r1]-(b:Comp) WHERE a.title IN custNames
OPTIONAL MATCH p2 = (a)-[:KNOWS]-(ka:Cust) WHERE ka.title IN custNames 
RETURN a.title, 
       extract(i IN relationships(p)| type(i)) as relation, 
       b.title, 
       extract(x IN nodes(p2)[1..] | x.title)
```

Comment: nice, "ka" was a great idea